# Confusion and Issue in the Database access in Rails app pushed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, configuration

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: myapp
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  port: 5432


test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: myapp-test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  port: 5432

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

selenium:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: myapp-selenium
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  port: 5432

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

My database values are updated but its not getting fetched on same time, do I need to change the production configuration?

Comment: can you try change the production same like development ?

Comment: will it be ok ?
production:
adapter : postgresql
database: production/artface
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
username:postgres
password:postgres

Comment: can u tell me in your devlopment side which database used

Comment: mentioned that, I am using posgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku replaces your database.yml entirely when you deploy your application at Heroku. You can confirm that by doing `heroku run bash` and then navigating to config folder and doing `cat database.yml` you will see they rewrite it to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Comment: or by running `heroku run cat config/database.yml` directly.

Comment: more details on the process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#rails and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Heroku replaces your Production configuration with the appropriate values.

You can even try pushing your app with no production configuration and it will work.

If you are trying different databases maybe this will be helpful: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

Answer (score -1):

Hello please refer database.yml

```
 production:
  adapter: PostgreSQL
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: "Your database name"
  pool: 5
  username: "username"
  password: "password"
  host: 127.0.0.1
```